# Why does FIND evaluate to #VALUE! when it doesn't find the value?

Tags: excel-formula

I'm using this Excel formula:

```
=IF(FIND("Door", D2, 1),F2, 0)
```

However, it evaluates to `#VALUE!` when the value is not found. In that case, I want the formula to evaluate to `0`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ISNUMBER()`.

Find returns the relative position of the text if found, and a `#VALUE!` error (not `FALSE`) if not.

If the condition returns an error, then the `IF` will return that error.

So, use this instead:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Door", D2, 1)),F2, 0)
```

Comment: You are a * Tks